# Rselenium Jsonlite scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium, jsonlite

I am new at Scraping. I am trying to **scrape** the **table** that appears in a site and transform into a *dataframe* but it seems that I have to execute a Script. I am using Rselenium approach. Probably *Jsonlite* works better, but I don´t know how.

```
# Running without problem
require(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
url <- "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento=62839&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2"
remDr$navigate(url)

# Here is my problem
remDr$findElement('id', 'ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados')$getElementText()[[1]]
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to deterministically get to the page with the table without logging in (which the vast majority of us can't do). It's a gosh awful SharePoint site and it uses a fairly heavyweight "View State" tracker to maintain state, so you should start from the beginning page, orchestrate a login and likely orchestrate button clicks. Lastly, the final page is actually a page with an `iframe` so you'll have to targret the `iframe` when you're getting the page source. Hopefully someone else with a bit more spare time can provide a representative code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a three tricky things about this page: 1) It's an iFrame, 2) cookies are required to access the "unframed" page, and 3) It's written in javascript, witch I find more difficult to scrape.

If you don't mind, I've used CVM's page instead of BM&FBovespa and used BRF as an example.
To find the income statement, go to [CVM's page](http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/) > "Companhias" (on your left hand side) > click on "Consulta de Documentos de Companhias Abertas" > choose the company > click DFP > and finally, select "Consulta" right above the desired document.

`u1` is the url generated by the path mentioned above. Use the Chrome's SelectorGadget or look into your browser's dev tools and you will find  `u2`. Personally, I find SelectorGadget easier to use. When you launch it, it will give you an url that lets you select in the iFrame.

```
u1 <- "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?CodigoTipoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=62776"

u2 <- "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmDemonstracaoFinanceiraITR.aspx?Informacao=2&Demonstracao=4&Periodo=0&Grupo=DFs+Consolidadas&Quadro=Demonstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o+do+Resultado&NomeTipoDocumento=DFP&Titulo=Demonstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20do%20Resultado&Empresa=BRF%20SA&DataReferencia=31/12/2016&Versao=1&CodTipoDocumento=4&NumeroSequencialDocumento=62776&NumeroSequencialRegistroCvm=1413&CodigoTipoInstituicao=1"
```

If close your browser and go straight to `u2`, the website will return an error message saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". To get rid of this, you want to pass the cookies from `u1` to `u2`.

```
r <- GET(u1)
biscoitos <-  cookies(r) #cookies de acesso para u2
page <- GET(u2, encoding = "utf-8",
               set_cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId" = biscoitos$value[1] , 
                           "BIGipServerpool_www.rad.cvm.gov.br_443" = biscoitos$value[2], 
                           "TS01871345" = biscoitos$value[3]))
pg_content <- content(page, "raw")
```

If this page was written in html, one could use the`#clt00_cphPopUp_tbDados` selector. I've found this weird workaround the javascript.

```
writeBin(pg_content, "temp.txt")
html_page <- read_html("temp.txt", encoding = "utf-8")
write_html(html_page, "temp.html", encoding = "utf-8")
df <- readHTMLTable("temp.html", encoding = "utf-8")
df <- df$ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados
```

[This httr tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) helped me write this piece of code.